# Posterior distribution in Bayesian linear regression - why not include $p(X | \beta, \sigma^2)$?

Tags: regression, bayesian, multiple-regression, bayes, posterior

Given parameter/s $\theta$, data $X$ and prior on the parameter/s $p(\theta)$, Bayes' theorem allows us to estimate the posterior distribution $p(\theta | X)$:

$p(\theta | X) = \frac{p(\theta) p(X | \theta)}{p(X)}$

$\to p(\theta | X) \ \propto \ p(\theta) p(X | \theta)$

From the [Bayesian linear regression Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_linear_regression#Posterior_distribution):

$p(\beta, \sigma^2 | y, X) \ \propto \ p(y | X, \beta, \sigma^2) p(\beta | \sigma^2) p(\sigma^2)$

I was expecting something like:

$p(\beta, \sigma^2 | y, X) \ \propto p(y | X, \beta, \sigma^2) \color{red}{p(X | \beta, \sigma^2)} p(\beta | \sigma^2) p(\sigma^2)$ or

since I guess

$p(\beta, \sigma^2, y, X) = p(y | X, \beta, \sigma^2) p(X, \beta, \sigma^2)$

Without $p(X | \beta, \sigma^2)$, I guess it's still true, but why not include it?

Comment: In the usual regression model, $X$ is not treated as a random variable.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for commenting. I thought Bayesians treat everything as random? Or not? '[The regressors xij may be viewed either as random variables, which we simply observe, or they can be considered as predetermined fixed values which we can choose. Both interpretations may be appropriate in different cases, and they generally lead to the same estimation procedures; however different approaches to asymptotic analysis are used in these two situations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression)'

Comment: Bayesians don't treat "everything" as random. While you can view X as random, it only "leads to the same estimation procedures" if you condition on X. In which case, again, X will stay on the RHS of the conditioning bar

Comment: @Glen_b Is it that frequentists treat the X's as random and parameters fixed and reverse for Bayesians? Or what?

Comment: Neither. In either case, we can condition on X throughout, or treat the X's as fixed. The effect is the same. So a frequentist can write either $E(Y|X) = X\beta$ or just $E(Y)=X\beta$ depending on which they do, though arguably the first covers both cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$X$ does not depend on $\beta$, $\sigma$.  These values have to do with getting $y$ from $x$.  So $P(X| \beta, \sigma)=P(X)$.  Since we are maximizing with respect to $\theta$ we don't care about this constant term.